# Is there a shortcut to search in the Windows services list?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-services

Does anyone know, if there is a shortcut to search a service in the Windows services list ?

I tried the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> but no way.

Comment: What? Maybe something like `Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "sql*"}` in PowerShell

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Is a shortcut to search a service in the Windows services list?

There doesn't appear to be one. Here are two workarounds.

---

#### Workaround #1 Export the list of Services to a Text File

Export the service list to a text file, and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> in your favourite editor.

To export, use one of the following:

- "Action" > "Export List ..."

  [image]
- Press the "Export List" toolbar button.

  [image]

Example output (services.txt):

[image]

---

#### Workaround #2 Use `wmic` and `findstr` in a `cmd` shell.

Open a `cmd` shell, run `wmic service` and pipe to `findstr`.

Example:

```
> wmic service | findstr -i bonjour
FALSE        TRUE        Bonjour Service                                                         0           Win32_Service      Enables hardware devices and software services to automatically configur
e themselves on the network and advertise their presence.



                                                                                                                 FALSE            Bonjour Service
  Normal        0                      Bonjour Service                 "C:\Program Files\Bonjour\mDNSResponder.exe"


                                                                                                           1940       0                        Own Process    TRUE     Auto       LocalSystem
       Running  OK      Win32_ComputerSystem     HAL         0      0
```

Note that the above is actually a single line of output that is wrapped by the `cmd` shell.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.

Comment: Note that as of Windows 10 build 1803 (and possibly earlier), the "Export List" option is no longer available.

Answer (score 7):

I would just use PowerShell. For example matching on the DisplayName (partial matches work here)

```
Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "sql*"}
```

returns a match

> Running  SQLWriter          SQL Server VSS Writer

You can also use -eq (equals) or look at the service name ($_.Name).